# How to anchor a drawing/line of a jpanel inside a jframe?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, awt

I want to make the line I draw of a jpanel not change when I resize the jframe that its on. I just want it to remain in it's original position and if I resize the jframe its on to be smaller, then part of the line should be hidden rather than the line being resized?

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.*;

public class GUIIntroduction {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        DrawPanel panel = new DrawPanel();
        JFrame app = new JFrame();
        panel.setBounds(0,0,60,60);
        app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        app.add(panel);
        app.setSize(600,600);
        app.setVisible(true);
    }
}

import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class DrawPanel extends JPanel{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        g.drawLine(0,height,width,0);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> g.drawLine(0,height,width,0);

If you don't want the size of the line to change, then why are you using dynamic variables in the painting method

The values of width and height change as the frame is resized.

Just use:

```
g.drawLine(0, 100, 100, 0);
```